# Powershell way of doing redircmp and redirusr

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I've used redircmp and redirusr for as long as I can remember to change the location for new user and computer accounts in a domain. It has worked flawlessly time and time again. However, I am doing more of my work now in PowerShell than ever before and although I can/could still run these commands via PowerShell... I have this itch I want to scratch to do it a different way... "The PowerShell Way"... if such a way exists. Initially I thought I could use Set-ADDomain, but I kept hitting a roadblock and was wondering if anyone had any insight on how to do this better, if there even is one...

```
$ADDomain = Get-ADDomain
$NewComputersOU = Get-ADGroup <target OU>
Set-ADDomain -Identity $ADDomain.ObjectGUID -Replace @{"ComputersContainer"="$($NewComputersOU.DistinguishedName)"}
```

And the error:

```
Set-ADDomain : The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist
```

I tried a ton of different ways to create the hash for the replace command without any difference and there weren't too many examples of using "Set-ADDomain" with the "-Replace @{" method. And, none of them ever show changing the "ComputersContainer" or the "UsersContainer" values.

Eventually I ran the "Get-Member" against the domain object which shows that both the ComputersContainer and UsersContainer only support "get" but not "set" functions. So, I feel like my initial approach looking for a simple solution is a dead end.

I ran across this post in searching for a viable answer, but it seems less than elegant...

https://www.open-a-socket.com/2015/02/20/redirecting-users-and-computers-containers-with-powershell/

I'm curious if there's another way that I'm missing that's more in tune with PowerShell commands that isn't so clunky. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

OK... so... "Well Known Objects" are... well known! :)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/5a00c890-6be5-4575-93c4-8bf8be0ca8d8

The GUID for new computers will always be: "AA312825768811D1ADED00C04FD8D5CD"

and the new user GUID will always be: "A9D1CA15768811D1ADED00C04FD8D5CD"

That said, the post I previously linked to: searched for, disassembled, and then reassembled the well known object. And, in doing so was a few more steps than was needed IMHO. So, the solution I went with was ever so slightly fewer steps and in a condensed version basically goes like this...

```ps1
$ADDomain = Get-ADDomain
$NewComputersOU = "DistinguishedName for your OU/Container of Choice"
$WellKnownComputerObject = "B:32:AA312825768811D1ADED00C04FD8D5CD:"
Set-ADObject -Identity $ADDomain -Add @{wellKnownObjects = $($WellKnownComputerObject + $NewComputersOU)} `
                -Remove @{wellKnownObjects = $($WellKnownComputerObject + $ADDomain.ComputersContainer)}
```

That's not the complete code... but you get the idea. It's not as elegant as I was hoping for... but it gets the job done without calling redircmp. Not that there's anything particularly evil or wrong with calling it. I was just rather hoping that there was an elegant way of doing the task entirely via PowerShell. Oh well. On to the next project! :D